# Display Maps with multiple locations

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I am developing a bank applications in android, where i need to display the locations of all its branches in letters say A, B, C..., N in google maps. These locations are dynamic and need to set them on the fly when the server retrieves the locations. Please put your pointers on how to achieve the multiple locations display on google maps.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers:

**1.** First integrate a map in you application, you can use this blog post guide to do so:

[Google Maps API V2 Guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

**2.** Next you will need to receive those point you want to display from some kind of web service and parse into objects, if you receive this data a JSON you can use this guide to parse this data into some kind of Array/List.

[JSON Parsing](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=746)

**3.** then you should go over this Array/List and put all the markers in there on tha map using the following code:

```
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298))
                      .title("Melbourne")
                      .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```