# How to include google map on android to show multiple locations of perticular company?

Tags: android, google-maps

So basically i want to show the multiple locations of the office on google map within android application. And also wanted the company’s logo as the marker on map. 
I dont have any idea how to do this.

Any help would be great for me ..

sorry for the bad english

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948161/display-maps-with-multiple-locations   For custom marker, you can read google documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_a_marker

Comment: I gone through all steps .. but stuck with white screen .. with google name at left bottom of the fragment . Any help .. why this is happening .. ?

Comment: Are you putting it in asynctask()?

Comment: You need to put all of your heavy operation in asynctask()

Comment: Hey.. am done.. some problem with key.. am generating the key as local user and running android studio as root. such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

to get started on google maps you need to read the documentation here, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro. After you complete the tutorial, you only need to add a mapFragment to the xml of the screen.

For setting up markers you need to get the mapFragment in the Activity.java:

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

and then set up a new marker:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MY_HOME).title("This is my home"));
```

MY_HOME contains a LatLng object with the latitud and longitud of the location.

Comment: I have gone through all the steps .. But my fragment shows white blank screen with google name at left bottom .. I tried various ways but could not load the map .. Dont know what to do ..

Comment: You are using fragmentManager() or supportFragmentManager()?, try switching thoose two methods.

Comment: I wanted to ask that .. while displaying google map on android .. how to load particular region ??